# iPart( and int( returning 0 for 1?

Tags: ti-basic

Ok, here's my problem. I wrote an advanced Pythagorean Theorem program, but it apparently is having exceptions. Here's an instance of my problem. When I input `A? √(3)` and `B? 2`, I get `0` back. Here's the code:

```
:Prompt A,C
:(C^2-A^2)->B
:If B<0
:Then
:Disp "THAT IS N
OT  A VALID TRIA
ANGLE
:Else
:If iPart(√(B))≠
√(B)
:Then
:Disp "B = √(",B
:Else
:Disp "B = ",√(B)
:End
:End
```

Therefore, if B = 1, then hypothetically it should output `B = 1` but instead it outputs:

```
A=? √(3)
C=? 2
B = √(
              1
           Done
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: What calculator are you using?  The language varies slightly per calculator.

Comment: @PGmath I'm using a TI-83

Comment: `iPart(` and `int(` have nothing to do with this problem; instead, the issue lies in the calculator's rounding error. In the second line, you store 4-√(3)² into B. Since the calculator rounds √(3) as a decimal, √(3)² becomes ever so slightly more than 3, so 4-√(3)² becomes something like 0.9999999999. Taking the `iPart(` of that will then give you 0, causing you the problem.

Comment: @user3932000 thanks for the explanation. That makes a lot more sense why the calculator would have such an odd rounding problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I quickly evaluate your program, it seems to work correctly when you get `B≠1`. For example if I want to calculate the famous 3,4,5 - triangle it shows:

```
A=?4
C=?5
B=
                  3
               Done
```

Apparently the `iPart(` doesn't work correctly with `√(1)`. You could include an extra statement to the `If iPart( ...` statement to rule this out. Like this.

```
:...
:If iPart(√(B))≠√(B) and B≠1
:...
```

Besides that I think the program looks cleaner and nicer if you use the `Input`, `ClrHome` and `Output(` commands.

```
:ClrHome
:Input "A: ",A
:Input "C: ",C
:(C^2-A^2)->B
:If B<0
:Then
:Output(4,1,"THA
T IS NOT A")
:Output(5,1,"VAL
ID TRIANGLE")
:Else
:If iPart(√(B))≠
√(B) and B≠1
:Then
:Output(3,1,"B: 
√( )")
:Output(3,5,B)
:Else
:Output(3,1,"B:")
:Output(3,5,√(B))
:End
:End
:Pause
:ClrHome
```

Now the results screen looks something like this:

```
A: √(3)
C: 2
B: 1
```

I think this is cleaner, with the `3` aligned istead of in the bottom right corner. When you press ENTER everything will remove itself from the screen (due to the `Pause` command).

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation and suggestion for a conditional statement. I appreciate the input!